# How to split one letter and dot into the different rows

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, explode

I have a dataframe with two columns, that is columns Word and Tag. The df:

```
                      Word   Tag
0                    Pada    A
1                 bakteri    B 
2                       ,    C 
3       ketumpangtindihan    D  
4                     ini    E
5             kemungkinan    F
6                terlibat    G
7                   dalam    H
8                regulasi    I
9             transkripsi    O
10                   gen.    O
```

and I'd like to separate some row contains one word with dot . `word+.` to be two row. So the output should be the following:

```
                      Word   Tag
0                    Pada    A
1                 bakteri    B 
2                       ,    C 
3       ketumpangtindihan    D  
4                     ini    E
5             kemungkinan    F
6                terlibat    G
7                   dalam    H
8                regulasi    I
9             transkripsi    O
10                    gen    O
11                      .    O
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance. If I did `explode`, the punctuation is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Heres an inefficient answer ;))

```
import pandas as pd

data = [['Alex.',10],['Bob',12],['Clarke',13]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Name','Age'])
for x in df['Name']:
  if (x[-1] =='.'):
    df['Name'].replace(x,x[:-1],inplace=True)
    df = df.append({'Name':'.','Age':14},ignore_index=True) #assign your tag
print(df)
```

Output before:

```
     Name  Age
0   Alex.   10
1     Bob   12
2  Clarke   13
```

output :

```
     Name  Age
0    Alex   10
1     Bob   12
2  Clarke   13
3       .   14
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
df['Word'] = df['Word'].str.split('(?<=\w)\.')
df = df.explode('Word')

map = df['Word'].groupby(level=0).cumcount().ge(1)
df.loc[map, 'Word'] = '.' + df.loc[map, 'Word']
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Some notes:

`(?<=\w)` - matches everything what has any alphanumeric character before

`\.` - matches dot

So in essence you will split by dot, preceded by alphanumeric. Then you will manually add dot in front of every second, and later elements of splitted string.

Outputs in your case:

```py
                 Word Tag
0                Pada   A
1             bakteri   B
2                   ,   C
3   ketumpangtindihan   D
4                 ini   E
5         kemungkinan   F
6            terlibat   G
7               dalam   H
8            regulasi   I
9         transkripsi   O
10                gen   O
11                  .   O
```

Comment: I got this error ```ValueError: split() requires a non-empty pattern match.```

Comment: Try upgrading your `pandas` otherwise you will have to drop 'dot' from the split and replace the pattern with: `'(?<=\w)\.'`.

Comment: I have tried to replace  the pattern with: ```'(?<=\w)\.'``` but the output changed dot with empty row  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LsjHq74zA4juaoRBRdXIhq1b8w7C6zee/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Yup, that's what will happen unless you upgrade, you cannot split by empty character (i.e. you cannot split without losing separator) otherwise

Comment: I have upgraded to pandas-1.1.3, but the output is still the same

Comment: Please see the answer now - it's odd with this regex though - the current version should work either way @winnie